# @JmsListener to listen multiple topics is listening to only one topic

Tags: java, spring

I have two @jmsListeners in a class in my spring boot application .Both are listening to ActiveMQ TOPICs.But It listens only one topic not both.Need help

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${foo1}", containerFactory = "foo1Factory")
public void onmessage(final Message message) throws JMSException, InvalidProtocolBufferException {
    sysout("Received status message: {}", message);
}

@JmsListener(destination = "${foo2}", containerFactory = "foo2Factory")
public void onmessage(final Message message) throws JMSException, InvalidProtocolBufferException {
    sysout("Received status message: {}", message);
}
```

//JMS Configuration:

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {

    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new

    ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
    connectionFactory.setUserName(userName);
    connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
    return connectionFactory;
}
@Bean(name = "foo1Factory")
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory QueueOUTFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
    factory.setConcurrency("1-2");
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    return factory;
}
@Bean(name = "foo2Factory")
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory QueueOUTFactory1(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
        factory.setConcurrency("1-2");
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }
```

Comment: You didn't show your actual `@JmsListener` methods.'

Comment: It supposed to print both the messages, unfortunately it is listening only one

Comment: Hi Sandeep! Welcome to stackoverflow. 
One quick check -- what are the values that you are providing for `${foo1}` and `${foo2}`. Ensure that they are pointing to the respective endpoint names in your properties file.

Comment: Hi snmaddula, ${foo1} and ${foo2} are the respective TOPICs..at a time only one topic is listening, I want both the topics to be listened

Comment: Your response ignores my comment. Post your real code.

Comment: Thanks everyone.It worked ..It was the problem with the delay in waiting..